# Ubuntu can't read temperature sensors?

Tags: graphics, hardware, fan, temperature, sensors

**Edit:** it's still problematic because the names aren't very descriptive. Based on past values (from Windows) I can sort of deduce what is what, but it's still uncertain. **The problem is that the reading names are not descriptive.** I'll open a new question for that though.

I'm trying to read my temprature sensor values using Xsensors and Psensor, but both programs only show a single value - what I suspect to be the CPU core temperature.

Here's a screenshot to illustrate:

[image]

I would like to also see:

- GPU temperature
- CPU socket temperature
- disk drives temperatures
- fan speeds if possible
- etc - everything programs like HWMonitor can show on Windows basically

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run `sudo sensors-detect`, **answer yes to all the questions** (including the one about writing it to `/etc/modules`), and then run `sudo service kmod start`, and reboot.

[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto)

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot of working programs showing the values]